# Проблема в Yii2. Undefined index: parent_id

Tags: php, yii2

```
protected function getTree(){
    $tree = [];
    debug($this->data);//тестовая ф-ция выводит массив категорий как положено
    foreach ($this->data as $id=>&$node) 
        if (!$node['parent_id']){//здесь возникает ошибка
            $tree[$id] = &$node;
        } else {
            $this->data[$node['parent_id']]['childs'][$node['id']] = &$node;
        }

    }
    return $tree;
}
```

Код перестал работать внезапно. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предупреждение говорит о том что не существует ключа `parent_id` в массиве `$node`.

Измените проверку:

```
if (!isset($node['parent_id'])){
```

Вредный совет - выключите предупреждения:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: Только вот до этого работало. Код я не трогал. Может с БД что-то.